# Does a C++ function that returns, but doesn't use, a type need to #include that type?

Tags: c++

Does this file required an `#include` to define `FooType`? The function's type signature returns `FooType*` but the function implementation doesn't use `FooType`.

```
// test.cpp
class FooType;  // Unresolved forward declaration

FooType* GetFoo() { return nullptr; }
```

It builds without warnings using `g++ --std=c++11 -Wall`. So is this a legal use of forward declaration?

Comment: Yes this is legal.

Comment: @HAG: Agreed, the bullet point "*Define* functions or methods which accept/return pointers/references to the incomplete type (but without using its members):" answers my exact question.

Comment: @mgiuffrida  right :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class):

> A declaration of the following form
>
> class-key attr identifier ;
>
> Declares a class type which will be
>   defined later in this scope. Until the definition appears, this class
>   name has incomplete type.
>
> ...
>
> and if a particular source file only uses pointers and references to
>   the class, this makes it possible to reduce #include dependencies.

So this syntax is perfectly valid, because you use a pointer `Foo*`.